# 2 related content types in Views with date field

Tags: entities, datetime, views

In a new project I want to create a View which displays 2 related content types.

The first content type is a school subject having a Date Repeat field with perhaps a weekly repeating rule.

The second content type is a homework with a single Date field and a entity reference field referencing a school subject.

The View I want to generate should be a typical diary which primarily shows the school subjects with a contextual filter set to weekly granularity to first show up the current week. I added the ID of the node, the node title, the date repeat field as fields to display and came across the idea to display the certain homeworks as a child View with the Views Field View module.

The child View should display the homeworks depending on the ID of the relating subject and depending on the time. That arguments come from the subjects in the parent View via the Views Field View module whereas it was easy to pass the node ID as an argument. The problem is about the repeating date field as an argument to the child View. I thought I can do that with a contextual Filter in the child View but with the other filters it seems more logical to me because the contextual filter doesn't work as I want to or rather doesn't working at all. But I cannot pass an argument to the filter in child View from the parent View, can't I?

I hope someone's out there who can help me with it before it finally drives me crazy :)

**Edit:**

I encountered that it's a bug. When I manually type the Contextual Filters in the preview field of the child View it works properly. So I came across this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1914780#comment-7565747

The problem is that date field returns the current date and not the date it contains?! Thats why my view displays content if I set the granularity to 'month' because the displayed fields are set to november but displays nothing when the granularity is set to 'day' which I want to achieve. I tried the hack mentioned in the link above but that returns the current date as well.

I'm confused. Maybe someone has an explanation for that. I would be really grateful!

I also tried to use the Views EVI module or the Views Filter Args module so I can create more complex filters with the date module, but on a date filter you cannot type arguments which are no date-formats.

The Child View: [image: Child View]

The parent View: [image: parent View]